# Gedit start problem in kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, gedit, segmentation-fault

I try to open gedit after install third party plugins but it won't open.
When i try it by terminal it shows

```
root@localhost:~# gedit 
Segmentation fault
```

I think gedit is running background but it don't. I restart my pc two and three time but it won't open. How do i solve this problem ?

I debug the apps and it shows

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004535ec in ?? ()
```

Comment: Remove the third party plugins, and report the problem to you distribution's maintainers and / or to the authors of said plugins.

Comment: Plugnis already removed...But not working yet...

Comment: @don_crissti, It don't work.

Comment: Try reinstalling gedit - seems the binary is b0rken.

Comment: @JennyD, i already do that, I try every think what i know, but it doesn't work